# Internal Server Error htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have htaccess line as per below:-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^articles/images/(.*)$ images/$1
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/images/(.*)$ images/$2

RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ articles.php?articleType=$1
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ articles.php?articleType=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ articles.php?articleType=$1&articleID=$2
```

The problem is if I comment `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]`, `http://localhost/trip/articles/Sightseeing` can be display. But I cannot display `http://localhost/trip/privacy` (Error: Object not found!). If I uncomment the line, I can display `http://localhost/trip/privacy` but cannot display `http://localhost/trip/articles/Sightseeing` (Error: Internal Server Error).

I already tried insert `<Directory /> AllowOverride All </Directory>` and got error: Server error! and insert `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>...</IfModule>` and got error: Internal Server Error.

Is there any way for both link be display successfully? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. For those who have same problem as mine:-

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^articles/images/(.*)$ images/$1

RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)/images/(.*)$ images/$2

RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ articles.php?articleType=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ articles.php?articleType=$1&page=$2 
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ articles.php?articleType=$1&articleID=$2
```

Comment: Hmm not a portable solution since now rules cannot rewrite `/dir/file` to `/dir/file.php` as you have `^([^/]+)$` regex pattern.